# Reporting on multiple tables independently in Crystal Reports 11

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am using Crystal Reports Developer Studio to create a report that reports on two different tables, let them be "ATable" and "BTable". For my simplest task, I would like to report the count of each table by using Total Running Fields. I created one for ATable (Called ATableTRF) and when I post it on my report this is what happens:

1) The SQL Query (Show SQL Query) shows:

```
SELECT "ATABLE"."ATABLE_KEY"
FROM   "DB"."ATABLE" "ATABLE"
```

2) The total records read is the number of records in ATable.

3) The number I get is correct (total records in ATable).

Same goes for BTableTRF, if I remove ATableTRF I get:

1) The SQL Query (Show SQL Query) shows:

```
SELECT "BTABLE"."BTABLE_KEY"
FROM   "DB"."BTABLE" "BTABLE"
```

2) The total records read is the number of records in BTable.

3) The number I get is correct (total records in BTable).

**The problems starts** when I just put both fields on the reports. What happens then is that I get the two queries one after another (since the tables are not linked in crystal reports):

```
SELECT "ATABLE"."ATABLE_KEY"
FROM   "DB"."ATABLE" "ATABLE"

SELECT "BTABLE"."BTABLE_KEY"
FROM   "DB"."BTABLE" "BTABLE"
```

And the number of record read is far larger than each of the tables - it doesn't stop. I would verify it's count(ATable)xcount(BTable) but that would exceed my computer's limitation (probably - one is around 300k rows the other around 900k rows).

I would just like to report the count of the two tables. No interaction is needed - but crystal somehow enforces an interaction.

Can anyone help with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some join describing the two tables' relationship, then the result will be a Cartesian product. Try just using two subqueries, either via a SQL Command or as individual SQL expressions, to get the row counts. Ex:

`select count(distinct ATABLE_KEY) from ATABLE`

If you're not interested in anything else in these tables aside from the row counts, then there's no reason to bring all those rows into Crystal - better to do the heavy lifting on the RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I looked more and indeed found that crystal performs a cartesian product on the two tables. However, I need to make additional manipulations on the data. For example, use parameters etc. When using parameters - I cannot use SQL Expression Field or create an aggregate view to show what I need. Still, I need to report on two different tables. Is there a way to report on two different tables in the same report without doing ANY join whatsoever? Thanks again!

Comment: @user1177650 This is not just Crystal, but any RDBMS will create a Cartesian product between tables when no relation is defined. If you want to grab data from two unrelated tables, you can create a SQL Command and write your own subqueries as the data source. This supports parameters.

Comment: Thanks all. The thing that got me confused is the fact that "Crystal Reports" enforces a join, and I wasn't aware of that. That being said, it is quite obvious that a cartesian product will be carried out, if no other method has been specified. In my opinion this enforcement of join is a _huge_ disadvantage since it doesn't allow to independently report on two or more different tables in the same report without any link between them.

Answer (score 0):

You could UNION the two queries.  This would give you one record set containing rows from each query once.